# GTK2HS fails to install with recent cabal versions

Tags: haskell, gtk, cabal, gtk2hs

I'm starting a new project that will hopefully use gtk2hs. However, I can not get this package to install on my fairly typical Linux box. Here is the failure :

```
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs, /tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/dist/dist-sandbox-58b5f9c6/setup/SetupWrapper.o )

/tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:94:45:
    Ambiguous occurrence `moreRecentFile'
    It could refer to either `SetupWrapper.moreRecentFile',
                             defined at /tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:149:1
                          or `Distribution.Simple.Utils.moreRecentFile',
                             imported from `Distribution.Simple.Utils' at /tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:8:1-32

/tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:95:45:
    Ambiguous occurrence `moreRecentFile'
    It could refer to either `SetupWrapper.moreRecentFile',
                             defined at /tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:149:1
                          or `Distribution.Simple.Utils.moreRecentFile',
                             imported from `Distribution.Simple.Utils' at /tmp/cairo-0.12.4-4201/cairo-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:8:1-32
Failed to install cairo-0.12.4
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs, /tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/dist/dist-sandbox-58b5f9c6/setup/SetupWrapper.o )

/tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:94:45:
    Ambiguous occurrence `moreRecentFile'
    It could refer to either `SetupWrapper.moreRecentFile',
                             defined at /tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:149:1
                          or `Distribution.Simple.Utils.moreRecentFile',
                             imported from `Distribution.Simple.Utils' at /tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:8:1-32

/tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:95:45:
    Ambiguous occurrence `moreRecentFile'
    It could refer to either `SetupWrapper.moreRecentFile',
                             defined at /tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:149:1
                          or `Distribution.Simple.Utils.moreRecentFile',
                             imported from `Distribution.Simple.Utils' at /tmp/glib-0.12.4-4201/glib-0.12.4/SetupWrapper.hs:8:1-32
Failed to install glib-0.12.4
```

It seems to be related to recent cabal versions, since that used to work before. It seems to be a known bug (http://trac.haskell.org/gtk2hs/ticket/1292 , http://trac.haskell.org/gtk2hs/ticket/1291 and http://trac.haskell.org/gtk2hs/ticket/1289), however it has not moved for weeks. I am not sufficiently competent to suggest a good fix, so I would like your advice. This is very annoying since I am stuck on this important project, and it pains me to think that the main GUI lib of our language has been broken for many weeks now.

cabal-install version 1.18.0.2 using version 1.18.1.1 of the Cabal library / ghc 7.4.1

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can edit `Setup.hs` and change it to use explicit imports.

Comment: You can see from your error message that the issue is in the `cairo` package, in the file `SetupWrapper.hs`, which defines the function `moreRecentFile` but also imports a function of the same name from `Distribution.Simple.Utils` (part of the cabal library). Presumably that's a new function added to cabal since the `cairo` package was tested. [Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk2hs-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01338.html) is a patch I found with a quick google search; don't know the status.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the root of the problem is easy to fix. I have never used setup.hs files, I guess that confused me. I will probably take this path, and maybe try to get that fixed upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct solution for now is to build from darcs. Detailed instructions are given in the [Getting the latest and greatest](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/download/#Getting_the_Latest_and_Greatest) section of the installation instructions; the short version is:

```
darcs get --lazy http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs
cd gtk2hs
sh bootstrap.sh
```

---

**EDIT:** The official 0.12.5 release of gtk2hs from December 2013 supports cabal 1.18, so the above darcs instructions are no longer needed. The full installation instructions are still available from the [Gtk2Hs download page](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/download); the short version is:

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
cabal install gtk gtk3
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I am new to gtk2hs, do you know if they plan a bugfix release on Hackage soon ? Part of my motivation by coming here is to get that fixed for everyone, not just for me. Regards,

Comment: when doing this I get : "At least the following dependencies are missing:
cairo >=0.12.0 && <0.13" plus a bunch of other missing dependencies.

Comment: @JeremyKnees Please open a new question with the full details. Exactly what you tried, full error output, etc. Trying to cram all the relevant information into a comment is going to just be painful and unreadable.

Comment: This is the way to go until the fix is released to hackage. For people using cabal sandbox, I recommand making a "bootstrap-sandbox" from the bootstrap.hs file, **sharing the same sandbox** for all pacakges so that they build fine. Thank you Daniel.

Comment: hi @DanielWagner. Please could you help me understand what is blocking the release of a fixed version to Hackage ? Thank you

Comment: @PaulR I am dealing with depression, which makes it difficult for me to focus on my professional duties.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am sorry to read this, and I hope you will be back on your feet soon, strong. Life is a wonderful gift, in particular for smart people in peaceful countries. You are young and your life is so promising, so exciting. Take a break off keyboard, listen to good reggae music (loud), go out and drink beer with mates. Give your brain a good wash and treat yourself with much kindness. Time flies, enjoy it :D

Comment: @Paul, can you explain how to share this as a sandbox ? I don't see any bootstrap.hs file...

Comment: @miguel.negrao : a fixed version of Gtk2hs has now been released to hackage (gtk 0.12.5). Daniel could update its answer to reflect it, or maybe I could. You can build it with cabal sandbox : 1) install gtk2hs-builddeps, 2) add the sandbox bin dir to your path, 3) install gtk . Cheers

Comment: @PaulR It seems other folks have rejected your edit, which as far as I can tell was spot on. So that's a bit obnoxious. I'm going to apply your edit by hand (which means it will officially say I made the edit instead of you -- I hope that's okay).

Answer (score 2):

You can try with older `Cabal` version using `cabal install --cabal-lib-version=1.16.0 gtk`.

Comment: @jozefg it says `cabal-install` what `Cabal` version it should use to compile `Setup.hs`. It will help because `moreRecentFile` doesn't exist in `Cabal-1.16.0`. The issue with `moreRecentFile` is not the only one, I tried to install `gtk2hs` few weeks ago, and the `--cabal-lib-version` trick was the easiest solution I found.

Comment: Thank you Yuras for this tip. I might use it if I am really in a hurry, however my primary goal now is to get that sorted and fixed for everyone.